# Commerce: Update weight value based on quantity on cart

Tags: views, commerce

Use [Commerce Physical](https://www.drupal.org/project/commerce_physical) module to add weights to your products. E.g. product 1 is 1kg, so it means quantity of 2 would be total of 2kg, but adjusting the quantity on cart page, does not adjust the weight field value.

In this demo you can see how adjusting quantity and updating the cart updates the Total field, but not Weight.

[image]

Comment: Have you seen [this issue / comment](https://www.drupal.org/project/commerce_physical/issues/1431720#comment-11191303)? If not, do you think that might help?

Comment: But PHP filter is evil.